# Java - JMF unable to add a Capture or Video device

Tags: java, windows, video, jmf

I am trying to capture video via JMStudio.

When I try to run jmfinit it not detect my webcam and also the device is not listed in jmfregistry.

When I try to add a device manually it is giving me an error Could not add item

I have tried to run both (jmfinit and jmfregistry) as administrator and even tried to change the security settings but nothing seems to work.

I am using Windows 7 
I re-installed OS also..
Please find snap shots of error message.
[error popup message as shown in snapshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo3tU.png)

I'm getting below error when i try to run my application

```
Exception in thread "VFW Request Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JMFSecurityManager: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jmvfw in java.library.path
at com.sun.media.JMFSecurityManager.loadLibrary(JMFSecurityManager.java:206)
at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWCapture.<clinit>(VFWCapture.java:19)
at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWSourceStream.doConnect(VFWSourceStream.java:241)
at com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.VFWSourceStream.run(VFWSourceStream.java:763)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: AFAIR JMF only recognizes web cams that use the resolutions JMF was designed to understand at the time it was made (which, being long ago, amounts to 'very lo res'). You do know JMF was abandoned over a decade ago, right? You might have more luck embedding the Java-FX `MediaPlayer` in the app. (I think it handles web-cams).

Comment: Even it is not detecting... Capture device such as webcam

Comment: *"Even it is not detecting..."* Where 'it' is what exactly? JMF? `MediaPlayer`? Your cat? Now is a good time for more words, rather than less.

Comment: When I try to run jmfinit, JMF studio not detect my webcam this is main problem i'm facing..?? why it is not detecting?? My friend suggested me just re-install OS then it will detect so i install win7 again, after that also it is not detecting.

Comment: Finally I got solution,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution for above Problem..

**JMF Studio is 32 bit supporting software so we must install 32bit supported JDK and also Eclipse then we not get any exceptions and errors.**

Once Run your application then Automatically Your system webcam will "On".

Answer (score 0):

JMF Studio is 32 bit it not support to 64bit OS/Eclipse,
 and another reason is may be Environment variable not defined.